# install_man() doesn not take path of generated file

Tags: c, build, ninja, meson-build

I am working in a project where I need to build man page for `geoclue`.

I am using mesons's `install_man()` function (more detail [here](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#install_man)) to pass a generated file from `configure_file()` function (more detail [here](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#configure_file)).

However I am getting an error that for `install_man` that the specified file does not exist.

Most probably because it is being generated at the same time using `ninja -C build`

Is there any way I could get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from referring to [this issue](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/2135)

do something like this
`foo = configure_file(...)`
then do
`install_man(foo)`